# Partition not showing in file manager after formating

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, files, disk, disk-formatting

I formated one partition(volume 1) in disks app and then that partition not shows in files

i have one sdd(only one partition) and hdd(3 partitons)

[files not showing volume 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7fG1.png)

[disks app partition 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jou1W.png)

Comment: Why would it? Formatting removes partitions and file systems.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What is the exact steps you used to format it? Please edit the question and add this info do not add as a comment.